# gtk_widget_set_sensitive on Close Window button

Tags: c, gtk

How would you change the sensitivity of the close window button (the X in the top right corner of the window)?

Is it possible? It seems like the X button isnt really a widget and therefore cant be passed to this function.

I know there is gtk_window_set_deletable to completely remove the X button but that isnt an option that is available.

Thank you.

Comment: What about catching the quit event and hijacking it?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The close button isn't a widget; it is controlled by the window manager, not by GTK. The solution is to catch the `delete-event` event and block it, as Federico Culloca suggests.

Comment: Also, note that window themes for a window meneger never provide a "grayed-out" X button.